# Invalid renderer SDL2

Tags: c, sdl

I am looking through the code and i cant find solution for the problem of invalid renderer. I am beginner with SDL2 and i have to write code in pure C.
I think that in my code there is more errors but because of this one i cant go further. Code is half in polish language so if u cant get what is where i can rewrite this a bit . Problem occure when in main i try to load function"Odczyt_z_Pliku". Probably somewhere there is a problem.
SDL_GetError() says" invalid renderer.

```
            #include<SDL.h>
        #include<stdio.h>
        #include<SDL_image.h>
        #pragma warning(disable : 4996)
        #define WYSOKOSC_EKRANU 768
        #define SZEROKOSC_EKRANU 1024

        typedef enum bool{
            false,true
        }bool;

        typedef struct sTekstura {
            int wysokosc;
            int szerokosc;
            SDL_Texture *Tekstura;

        }sTekstura;

        void IniTekstury(sTekstura T)
        {
            T.wysokosc = 0;
            T.szerokosc = 0;
            T.Tekstura = NULL;
        }

        void free(sTekstura T)
        {
            //Free texture if it exists
            if (T.Tekstura != NULL)
            {
                SDL_DestroyTexture(T.Tekstura);
                T.Tekstura = NULL;
                T.szerokosc = 0;
                T.wysokosc = 0;
            }
        }

        int Odczyt_z_Pliku(char nazwa[50],sTekstura T,SDL_Renderer* Renderer)
        {
            free(T);

            SDL_Texture* nTekstura = NULL;

            //Load image at specified path
            SDL_Surface* Powierzchnia = IMG_Load(nazwa);
            if (Powierzchnia == NULL)
            {
                printf("Unable to load image %s! SDL_image Error: %s\n", nazwa, IMG_GetError());
            }
            else
            {
                SDL_SetColorKey(Powierzchnia, SDL_TRUE, SDL_MapRGB(Powierzchnia->format, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF));

                //Create texture from surface pixels
                nTekstura = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(Renderer, Powierzchnia);
                if (nTekstura == NULL)
                {
                    printf("Unable to create texture from %s! SDL Error: %s\n", nazwa, SDL_GetError());
                }
                else
                {
                    //Get image dimensions
                    T.szerokosc = Powierzchnia->w;
                    T.wysokosc = Powierzchnia->h;
                }

                //Get rid of old loaded surface
                SDL_FreeSurface(Powierzchnia);
            }

            //Return success
            T.Tekstura = nTekstura;
            if (T.Tekstura != NULL)
            {
                return 1;
            }
            else
            {
                return 0;
            }


        }
        bool Inicjalizacja(SDL_Window *Okno,SDL_Renderer *Renderer)
        {
            //Initialization flag
            bool success = true;

            //Initialize SDL
            if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) < 0)
            {
                printf("SDL could not initialize! SDL Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
                success = false;
            }
            else
            {
                //Set texture filtering to linear
                if (!SDL_SetHint(SDL_HINT_RENDER_SCALE_QUALITY, "1"))
                {
                    printf("Warning: Linear texture filtering not enabled!");
                }

                //Create window
                Okno = SDL_CreateWindow("SDL Tutorial", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SZEROKOSC_EKRANU, WYSOKOSC_EKRANU, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
                if (Okno == NULL)
                {
                    printf("Window could not be created! SDL Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
                    success = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    //Create renderer for window
                    Renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(Okno, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED | SDL_RENDERER_PRESENTVSYNC);
                    if (Renderer == NULL)
                    {
                        printf("Renderer could not be created! SDL Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
                        success = false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //Initialize renderer color
                        SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(Renderer, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF);


                        //Initialize PNG loading
                        int imgFlags = IMG_INIT_PNG;
                        if (!(IMG_Init(imgFlags) & imgFlags))
                        {
                            printf("SDL_image could not initialize! SDL_image Error: %s\n", IMG_GetError());
                            success = false;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            return success;
        }
        void setBlendMode(sTekstura T, SDL_BlendMode blending) //MK: Funkcja ustawiająca przezroczystosc
        {
            //Set blending function
            SDL_SetTextureBlendMode(T.Tekstura, blending);
        }

        void setAlpha(sTekstura T,Uint8 alpha)  //MK: Funkcja ustawiająca przezroczystość
        {
            //Modulate texture alpha
            SDL_SetTextureAlphaMod(T.Tekstura, alpha);
        }
        void render(int x, int y,sTekstura T,SDL_Renderer *Renderer)
        {
            //Set rendering space and render to screen
            SDL_Rect renderQuad = { x, y, T.szerokosc, T.wysokosc };
            SDL_RenderCopy(Renderer, T.Tekstura, NULL, &renderQuad);
        }


        int main(int argc, char *argv[])
        {
            SDL_Window * Okno = NULL;
            SDL_Renderer* Renderer = NULL;
            sTekstura TloMenu;
            TloMenu.szerokosc = 0;
            TloMenu.wysokosc = 0;
            TloMenu.Tekstura = NULL;
            sTekstura TloGra;
            TloGra.szerokosc = 0;
            TloGra.wysokosc = 0;
            TloGra.Tekstura = NULL;
            sTekstura Pudlo;
            Pudlo.szerokosc = 0;
            Pudlo.wysokosc = 0;
            Pudlo.Tekstura = NULL;
            sTekstura Sciana;
            Sciana.szerokosc = 0;
            Sciana.wysokosc = 0;
            Sciana.Tekstura = NULL;
            sTekstura StartGry;
            StartGry.szerokosc = 0;
            StartGry.wysokosc = 0;
            StartGry.Tekstura = NULL;
            sTekstura KoniecGry;
            KoniecGry.szerokosc = 0;
            KoniecGry.wysokosc = 0;
            KoniecGry.Tekstura = NULL;
            SDL_Event e;

            //Start up SDL and create window
            if (!Inicjalizacja(Okno,Renderer))
            {

                printf("Failed to initialize!\n");
            }
            else
            {

                if(!Odczyt_z_Pliku("MENU BOMBERMAN.png", Sciana, Renderer))
                {
                    puts("Nie wczytano kostki");
                    return 0;
                }
                if (!Odczyt_z_Pliku("pudlo3.bmp", Pudlo, Renderer))
                {
                    puts("Nie wczytano pudla");
                    return 0;
                }
                if (!Odczyt_z_Pliku("MenuBomberman.bmp", TloMenu, Renderer))
                {
                    puts("Nie wczytano menu");
                    return 0;
                }
                if (!Odczyt_z_Pliku("Mapa.bmp", TloGra, Renderer))
                {
                    puts("Nie wczytano mapy");
                    return 0;
                }
                if (!Odczyt_z_Pliku("NEW GAME.bmp", StartGry, Renderer))
                {
                    puts("Nie wczytano napisu nowej gry");
                    return 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    //Set standard alpha blending
                    setBlendMode(StartGry, SDL_BLENDMODE_BLEND);
                }
                if (!Odczyt_z_Pliku("exitgimp.bmp", KoniecGry, Renderer))
                {
                    puts("Nie wczytano napisu koniec gry");
                    return 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    //Set standard alpha blending
                    setBlendMode(StartGry, SDL_BLENDMODE_BLEND);
                }


                    //Main loop flag
                    bool quit = false;

                    //Modulation component
                    Uint8 AlphaStartu = 255;
                    Uint8 AlphaKonca = 127;

                    //While application is running
                    while (!quit)
                    {
                        //Handle events on queue
                        while (SDL_PollEvent(&e) != 0)
                        {
                            //User requests quit
                            if (e.type == SDL_QUIT)
                            {
                                quit = true;
                            }
                            //Handle key presses
                            else if (e.type == SDL_KEYDOWN)
                            {
                                //Increase alpha on w
                                if (e.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_w)
                                {
                                    AlphaKonca = 127;
                                    AlphaStartu = 255;
                                }
                                //Decrease alpha on s
                                else if (e.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_s)
                                {
                                    AlphaKonca = 256;
                                    AlphaStartu = 127;
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        //Clear screen
                        SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(Renderer, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF);
                        SDL_RenderClear(Renderer);

                        //Render background
                        render(0, 0, TloMenu, Renderer);

                        //Render front blended
                        setAlpha(KoniecGry,AlphaKonca);
                        setAlpha(StartGry, AlphaStartu);
                        render(0, 0,StartGry,Renderer);
                        render(0, 0,KoniecGry,Renderer);

                        //Update screen
                        SDL_RenderPresent(Renderer);
                    }

            }

            //Free resources and close SDL
            close();

            return 0;
        }
```

Comment: I was trying to change formats of surfaces from bmp to png and i tried changing SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED for SDL_RENDERER_SOFTWARE and it didnt work also

Comment: Calling your functions `free` and `close` is a really bad idea that will bite you at every step. Don't use standard library names.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you get to `Odczyt_z_Pliku`, `Renderer` is still a `NULL` pointer.

As it stands, in your `main()` function you have a variable `Renderer` of type `SDL_Renderer*` (initialized to `NULL`).  You then pass that value `NULL` into SDL_Renderer* which also takes an argument of type `SDL_Renderer*`.

However, in C this is just a pass by copy of the value of the pointer itself (not the value pointed to by the pointer).  In other words, the argument `Renderer` to your function just creates a local variable in that function.  So in `Odczyt_z_Pliku` when you do `Renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(...);` that may return a new pointer but it's only assigning it to the local variable `Renderer`, but this has no effect on the `Renderer` variable in your `main()` function.

In C, the way to write a function that sets the value of a pointer that is a local variable in the calling function is to use a *double pointer*.  That is, change the signature of `Inicjalizacja` to

```
bool Inicjalizacja(SDL_Window **Okno, SDL_Renderer **Renderer)
```

then in `main()` (or wherever else) call it like:

```
SDL_Window * Okno = NULL;
SDL_Renderer* Renderer = NULL;
...
if (!Inicjalizacja(&Okno, &Renderer)) {
...
}
```

and so on.  *(Note: You made the same mistake with the `SDL_Window` Okno as well, and possibly elsewhere--I haven't read the full code).*

The syntax `&Okno` means pass the address of (i.e. a pointer to) the variable `Okno`.  Since `Okno` is itself a pointer, the address of the pointer is a *double pointer*.

Then in `Inicjalizacja` write:

```
*Renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(...);
```

and similarly with `Okno`.  The `*Renderer` syntax (which I find somewhat confusing) means the value pointed to by a pointer.  Since `Renderer` here is a double pointer, this means assign the *single pointer* (of type `Renderer*`) into the pointer pointed to by `Renderer`.  Now the `Renderer*` pointer in your `main()` function will be properly initialized.

Note, similarly you should change the following check to:

```
if (*Renderer == NULL) {...}
```

and so on.  We *know* `Renderer != NULL` since it's a pointer to a local variable allocated in our `main()` function.  The interesting question is what value `SDL_CreateRenderer` returned, so we want to look at `*Renderer`.

Comment: As an aside, in `Inicjalizacja` you might consider just returning `false` as soon as some operation fails, rather that using the `success` variable and deep nesting.  You can see that for each operation, if any of the preceding operations failed then the initialization is unsuccessful, so you might as well un-nest everything and just perform all the operations one by one, returning `false` as soon as one fails.

Comment: Thank you very much know everything is ok