# Struct pointer remains NULL even after assignment

Tags: c, return

I am trying to return a Tuple struct from a function, but it seems like it isn't updating the pointer to which it is being assigned.

For instance, if I look at the value of the Tuple just before it is being returned I find that it is allocated properly:

```
342        Tuple *t = create_tuple();
(gdb) 
345        memcpy(t->part1, cwd, i + 1);
(gdb) p t
$5 = (Tuple *) 0x605010
(gdb) n
346        memcpy(t->part2, &cwd[i + 1], cwd_len - i - 1);
(gdb) 
348        return t;
```

But after it is assigned it looks like the tuple pointer which I assign to it is still NULL:

```
291              if ((partitioned = split_prefix(cwd, strlen(cwd))) == NULL)
(gdb) p partitioned
$11 = (Tuple *) 0x0
(gdb) n
296              memcpy(name_field, partitioned->part1, strlen(partitioned- 
>part1));
(gdb) p partitioned
$12 = (Tuple *) 0x0
```

I thought that since I return the pointer that isn't NULL it should be ok, so I am confused at how I can a NULL pointer before and after the call. Maybe I initialized the pointer incorrectly?

This is the function where the struct pointer returns to:

```
// gets name field and returns TRUE if successful, otherwise FALSE
int get_name_field(Tuple *partitioned, char name_field[], char *fname, char *cwd, int cwd_len)
{
   // fname cannot be broken up
   if (strlen(fname) > 155)
   {
      perror(fname);
      return FALSE;
   }
   // there is a path (prefix)
   else if (cwd)
   {
      // fname field isn't long enough
      if (strlen(cwd) + 1 + strlen(fname) > 100)
      {
         // ***********assignment here**************
         if ((partitioned = split_prefix(cwd, strlen(cwd))) == NULL)
         {
            perror("partition failed");
            return FALSE;
         }
         memcpy(name_field, partitioned->part1, strlen(partitioned->part1));
      }
...
```

The function returning the Tuple pointer:

```
// return a the part of prefix that fits in name field, and the remainder
// if no delimiter is found, returns null
Tuple *split_prefix(char *cwd, int cwd_len)
{
   // find last '/' delimiter that is within NAME_LEN range 
   int found = 0;
   int i = cwd_len <= 100 ? cwd_len - 1: NAME_LEN;
   for (; i > -1; i--)
   {
      if (cwd[i] == '/')
      {
         found = TRUE;
         break;
      }
   }

   // no delimiter found 
   if (!found)
   {
      return NULL;
   }
   // too long to be stored in overflow
   else if (cwd_len - i > PREFIX_LEN)
   {
      return NULL;
   }

   // **********Tuple created here************
   Tuple *t = create_tuple();

   // make partitions
   memcpy(t->part1, cwd, i + 1);
   memcpy(t->part2, &cwd[i + 1], cwd_len - i - 1);

   return t;
}
```

Tuple's definition:

```
#define NAME_LEN 100
#define PREFIX_LEN 155

// holds partioned strings of prefix
typedef struct Tuple
{
   char part1[NAME_LEN];
   char part2[PREFIX_LEN];
} Tuple;
```

To create Tuple:

```
// create a tuple with default values
Tuple *create_tuple(void)
{
   Tuple *t = malloc(sizeof(Tuple));
   memset(t->part1, '\0', NAME_LEN);
   memset(t->part2, '\0', PREFIX_LEN);

   return t;
}
```

Edit: The function that calls get_name_field:

```
void test_get_name_field3(void)
{
   Tuple *partitioned = NULL;
   char name_field[NAME_LEN] = {'\0'};
   char *fname = "hellobutunfortunatelythiswon'tfit.txt";
   char *cwd = "user/bin/arafian/ratherlongdirectorynameandwillnot/fitin"
               "thenamefieldonlysoitwilloverflowtotheprefixfield";
   int cwd_len = strlen(cwd);

   get_name_field(partitioned, name_field, fname, cwd, cwd_len);
   char *result = "user/bin/arafian/ratherlongdirectorynameandwillnot/";
   checkit_string(name_field, result);
   free(partitioned);
}
```

Comment: without looking at your code, take gdb output with a grain of salt, it has lied to me before (well, gdb + gdbserver). Maybe throw in some `printf`s to verify what gdb is telling you to fully justify banging your head against the wall.

Comment: Please post a MCVE. What is NAME_LEN and PREFIX_LEN? The split_prefix function might write out of bounds.  The calling code does `strlen(partitioned->part1)` but it's not clear if split_prefix terminated `part1`

Comment: @M.M I added the constants. Both part1 and part2 should be null terminated since create_tuple assigns both of the arrays to start as all null chars to begin with. At least that is what I tried to do.

Comment: I suggest using your length macros consistently instead of the mix of macros and magic numbers in the code. (Or preferably use `sizeof` on the arrays in question)

Comment: @M.M Yeah I thought that I wouldn't want many extra null bits, but that is a bad idea I think. Thanks.

Comment: If `i == 100` after the loop then `memcpy(t->part1, cwd, i + 1);` writes out of bounds; and if `i == 99` it generates a non null terminated string

Comment: @M.M That is true, but in this case i is only 50. `345        memcpy(t->part1, cwd, i + 1);
(gdb) p i
$2 = 50`

Comment: It is strange that the memcpy does not segfault even though I dereference a NULL pointer.

Comment: dereferencing a null pointer is *undefined behaviour*, which means anything can happen. You should not expect a segfault or any other particular thing

Comment: As suggested in comments to another answer, the expression starting `(partitioned =` inside `get_name_field` is suspicious . If that is actually the real code then you never use the initial value of `partitioned` and your comments suggest you think that this assignment somehow propagates to the calling function (it doesn't)

Comment: @M.M But when I do `memcpy(name_field, partitioned->part1, strlen(partitioned->part1));` in get_name_field the caller's Tuple will be changed right?

Comment: @dumbitdownjr No. There is no "caller's Tuple".  Maybe you mean the caller's `Tuple *`, that will not be changed at any point of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to return a pointer via an argument to a function, then that function must take a double pointer for an argument. I.e. `int get_name_field(Tuple **partition, ...) {` and called like `get_name_field(&partition, ...)`.

This is the exact same problem as in the question I recently answered here https://stackoverflow.com/a/50261485/982257 and probably several others.